# Possible to intercept reading of existing published property

Tags: delphi, components

I have a component with a published property. Imagine it as follows:

```
  TSomething = (sOne, sTwo, sThree, ...);
  TSomethings = set of TSomething;

  TSomeComponent = TWinControl
  private
    fSomethings: TSomethings;
    function GetSomethings: string;
    procedure SetSomethings(const Value: TSomethings);
  published
    property Somethings: TSomethings read GetSomethings write SetSomethings;
  end;
```

The problem is that TSomething now at max capacity for a published set (Compiler error E2187) so I need to split the set as follows:

```
  TSomething = (sTwo, sThree, ...);
  TSomethings = set of TSomething;

  // Some items moved from TSomething and named with an "o" prefix
  TOtherThing = (oOne, oThirtyThree, oThirtyFour, ...);
  TOtherThings = set of TOtherThing;

  TSomeComponent = TWinControl
  private
    fSomethings: TSomethings;
    fOtherThings: TOtherThings;
    function GetSomethings: string;
    procedure SetSomethings(const Value: TSomethings);
    function GetOtherThings: string;
    procedure SetOtherThings(const Value: TOtherThings);
  published
    property Somethings: TSomethings read GetSomethings write SetSomethings;
    property OtherThings: TOtherThings read GetOtherThings write SetOtherThings;
  end;
```

Some of the existing items in TSomethings have been moved to TOtherThings (logically categorized them), so some users will open their form to the error:

> Error reading SomeComponent1.Somethings: Invalid property value

So I'd like to silently handle the changes when a form is opened. In other words, intercept the reading of the Somethings property in the DFM and populate both the Somethings and OtherThings property.

But I cannot seem to find a way to do this. Overriding DefineProperties should work if I am willing to rename the old property completely, but that would needlessly break a lot of code (cure is worse than the ailment).

So is there another way I have overlooked?

Similar questions:

- ["Size of published set '%s' is >4 bytes". How to fix this compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123879/size-of-published-set-s-is-4-bytes-how-to-fix-this-compiler-error)
- [How to use GetSetProp and SetSetProp from TypInfo unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127079/how-to-use-getsetprop-and-setsetprop-from-typinfo-unit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had the published property SomeThings, which had more 32 items so needed to be split (or unpublished). I decided to logically split the existing items (categorize them), which made the process more complicated if I wanted to minimize broken code for existing users.

So I create two new properties, e.g. TheseThings, OtherThings.

Rather than removing the old SomeThings property, I changed it from Published to Public so existing user code would not break if they assigned (most) old properties to it at run-time.

In order to prevent an error when opening a form containing SomeThings items, I overrode DefineProperties() which correctly moved items into either the TheseThings or OtherThings properties.

```
procedure TMyUnit.ReadSomeThings(Reader: TReader);
  {}
  function ReadSet(): string;
  var
    EnumName: string;
  begin
    Result := '';
    try
      if Reader.ReadValue <> vaSet then
        raise Exception.Create('Not a set');
      while True do
      begin
        EnumName := Reader.ReadStr;
        if EnumName = '' then Break;
        Result := Result + EnumName + ',';
      end;
    except
      while Reader.ReadStr <> '' do begin end;
      raise;
    end;
  end;
  {}
  function NextWord(var P: PAnsiChar): AnsiString;
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    I := 0;
    while not (P[I] in [',', ' ', #0,']']) do
      Inc(I);
    SetString(Result, P, I);
    while P[I] in [',', ' ',']'] do
      Inc(I);
    Inc(P, I);
  end;
  {}
var
  s: AnsiString;
  P: PAnsiChar;
  enumName: AnsiString;
  ttSet: TTheseThings;
  otSet: TOtherThings;
begin
  s := AnsiString( ReadSet() );
  if s = '' then
    Exit;

  otSet := [];
  ttSet := [];

  P := PAnsiChar( s );

  enumName := NextWord(P);
  while enumName <> '' do
  begin
    // Convert item names of OtherThings property to newer names (changed prefix)
    if SameText( enumName, 'sTwo' ) then
      otSet := otSet + [oTwo ]
    else
    if SameText( enumName, 'sThree' ) then
      otSet := otSet + [ oThree ]
    else
...

   // Exiting items of TTheseThings have same name as old TSomeThings to minimize breakage
    else
    if SameText( enumName, 'sOne' ) then
      ttSet := ttSet + [ sOne ]
    else
    if SameText( enumName, 'sFour' ) then
      ttSet := ttSet + [ sFour ]
    else
...

    enumName := NextWord(P);
  end;

  if ttSet <> [] then
    SetTheseThings(ttSet);

  if otSet <> [] then
    SetOtherThings(otSet);
end;

procedure TMyUnit.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited;
  Filer.DefineProperty( 'SomeThings', ReadSomeThings, nil, False );
end;
```

Note: My original code used GetEnumValue(); to convert the enumName to an enumerator, but it was constantly giving me corrupted set values, so I opted for this simpler (but more wordy) solution

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to rename the existing properties, just make them `public` instead of `published` to disable native DFM streaming for them without breaking any user code, and then override `DefineProperties()` to handle DFM streaming for the properties as needed.

If you need to maintain design-time support, you could try [creating "fake" properties](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33448) for the Object Inspector to display so users can edit the values of the public properties as needed.  Or, it would likely be easier to just write a custom component editor instead that displays a modal Form to edit the values using a `TCheckListBox`, or a `TListView` with check boxes.

Comment: This would seem like a good solution, but I cannot find any examples of using fake properties for a set. In my testing, the fake property always operates like a drop down (despite changing what I thought were all the relevant methods), making it impractical for a property that allows multiple selection.

Comment: @Zax I didn't say it would be easy, just possible. Creating fake properties is not trivial, I'm sure most developers don't have need for it, and the few that do likely haven't documented their efforts very much. That being said, I have updated my answer with another suggestion

Comment: Thanks for your help, Remy. In the end I decided to rename the old property. (I know i said i would not do that, but I neglected to consider that I could just keep the old property as a "deprecated" public field, so no run-time functionality would be broken). I now have two new published properties, and use DefineProperties() to read the old property value and assign it to the correct new property (so no design-time functionality is broken). Although, I disliked having to rename the property (and keep the old one), this method means that the changes will not impact users at all.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, because although I did not use, it was part of the process that lead me to the solution I was happy with.

Comment: @Zax "*I now have two new published properties, and use DefineProperties() to read the old property value and assign it to the correct new property (so no design-time functionality is broken)*" - That is a good way to handle it.

Comment: @Zax "*I have accepted your answer, because although I did not use, it was part of the process that lead me to the solution I was happy with*" - feel free to [post your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and then [accept it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: OK, I'll do that